# Adding all image links to a colorbox on the site

Tags: jquery, gallery, colorbox

I'm using colorbox on: http://www.rheolas.com/tsalapeng

I want to set it to automatically add all colorbox links on a page to a set, so you can browse through them with the left right arrows.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give the anchor-tag same class name, and call the colorbox with rel parameter like this :

```
$(".classname").colorbox({rel:'classname'});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a rel in your settings for colorbox.

So instead of

```
jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5,  maxWidth:"90%", maxHeight:"90%"});
```

you need to do something like

```
jQuery('a.gallery').colorbox({ opacity:0.5,  maxWidth:"90%", maxHeight:"90%", rel:"group1" });
```